# Fork/Join – правильно ли я сделал это?

Tags: java

Создайте синхронную многопоточную систему для определения суммы всех целых чисел или дробей в трех текстовых файлах. Как правильно реализовать forkjoin, я не понимаю, что рекурсивно вызывать в recursivetask и как вернуть два значения.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;
 
 
public class loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
        File[] files = {
                new File("text"),
                new File("text2"),
                new File("text3")
        };
 
        SumOfDigits sumOfDigits = new SumOfDigits(files);
 
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
 
 
        System.out.println(sumOfDigits.invoke());
 
 
    }
}
 
class SumOfDigits extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {
    File[] files;
 
    public SumOfDigits(File[] files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
 
    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {
        if(files.length > 1){
            return ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(createSubtasks())
                    .stream()
                    .mapToInt(ForkJoinTask::join)
                    .sum();
        }else {
            return processing(files);
        }
    }
 
    private Collection<SumOfDigits> createSubtasks() {
        List<SumOfDigits> dividedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        dividedTasks.add(new SumOfDigits(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(files, 0, files.length / 2)));
        dividedTasks.add(new SumOfDigits(
                Arrays.copyOfRange(files, files.length / 2, files.length)));
        return dividedTasks;
    }
 
    private Integer processing(File[] files) {
        int resultInt = 0;
        double resultDouble = 0.0;
 
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(files[0])) {
            System.out.println(new Thread().getId());
            System.out.println(files[0].getName());
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                String num = sc.next();
                if (num.matches("^\\d+$")
                ) {
                    resultInt += Integer.parseInt(num);
                } else if (num.matches("[0-9]+(\\.)[0-9]*")) {
                    resultDouble += Double.parseDouble(num);
                    System.out.println(new Thread().getId());
                }
            }
            System.out.println(new Thread().getId() + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(resultDouble + " " + resultInt);
        return resultInt;
 
    }
}
```